# Login to Yahoo via Query in a Macro. cookie passing?

Tags: vba, excel-web-query

I have a table that i need to import from yahoo that I want to run as a macro. Macro Recorder does this fine, however when i set up the query (when recording) I have to first login and then select the table.

The query works within the macro as long as I don't close out of excel. When i reenter excel, it seems the cookie is lost and it does not work unless i login to yahoo via the query interface. I have tried opening a new IE window and logging in through there but it seems the cookie does not pass to the query.

Does anyone have an idea on how i could work around this where I either put my login credentials in some inputput box or pass this cookie from an ie window the user would fill out?

here is what the macro recorder returns when i try to import the yahoo login page (after signing in via the web connection window)

```
Sub Macro1()
With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="URL;https://login.yahoo.com", _
        Destination:=Range("$A$1"))
        .CommandType = 0
        .Name = "login.yahoo"
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .BackgroundQuery = True
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .WebSelectionType = xlEntirePage
        .WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingNone
        .WebPreFormattedTextToColumns = True
        .WebConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne = True
        .WebSingleBlockTextImport = False
        .WebDisableDateRecognition = False
        .WebDisableRedirections = True
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
End Sub
```

edit: i am trying to go about this in a different way. So i have logged in to yahoo via the following method:

```
Sub gotosite()
Dim IE As Object
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
IE.Navigate "http://login.yahoo.com"
'IE.Visible = True
'apiShowWindow IE.hwnd, SW_MAXIMIZE
Do While IE.Busy: DoEvents: Loop
Do While IE.ReadyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop
IE.Document.all("login").Value = "username"
IE.Document.all("passwd").Value = "password"
IE.Document.all(".save").Click
Do While IE.Busy: DoEvents: Loop
Do While IE.ReadyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop

IE.Navigate "http://football.fantasysports.yahoo.com/archive/nfl/2013/715896/draftresults"
'IE.Visible = True
'apiShowWindow IE.hwnd, SW_MAXIMIZE
Do While IE.Busy: DoEvents: Loop
Do While IE.ReadyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop
```

this will bring the page to the site i am trying to scrape. the source code of interest looks like this:

```
<div id="drafttables" class="round">
<div class="yui-gb">
<div class="yui-u first">
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="simpletable">
<thead>
 <tr>
   <th colspan="3">Round 1</th>
 </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr class="odd"> <td class="first">1.</td>
 <td class="player" nowrap><a href="http://sports.yahoo.com/nfl/players/8261" target="sports" class="name">Adrian Peterson</a>  <span>(Min - RB)</span></td>
 <td class="last" title="Tale of the Gerbil">Tale of the ...</td>
</tr>
<tr class="even"> <td class="first">2.</td>
 <td class="player" nowrap><a href="http://sports.yahoo.com/nfl/players/25741" target="sports" class="name">Doug Martin</a>  <span>(TB - RB)</span></td>
 <td class="last" title="Michael Korte's Team">Michael Kort...</td>
</tr>
<tr class="odd"> <td class="first">3.</td>
```

does anyone know how to loop through this code, return all the class="name"> values and the next "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first attempt (using QueryTables, which is a pretty unreliable way to scrape data from the web) did you try simply telling it to remember the password? Right now, you have:

```
.SavePassword = False
```

Try:

```
.SavePassword = True
```

To your second question:

> does anyone know how to loop through this code, return all the class="name"> values and the next

Something like this (which requires IE8+ to use the `GetElementsByClassName` method.

```
Dim ele as Object

For each ele in IE.Document.GetElementsByClassName("name")

    Debug.Print ele.Value ' or ele.InnerText, etc...

Next
```